# what book would you recommend for developing workflows in visual studio

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, books

What books would you recommend for developing workflows in visual studio 2010? I'm wanting something that doesn't just cover the basics. -thanks,

Comment: Sharepoint workflows, or workflows in general?

Comment: Sharepoint workflows, but other windows workflows would be beneficial as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two recommendations:

Professional Workflow in SharePoint 2010: Real World Business Workflow Solutions (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Workflow-SharePoint-2010-Programmer/dp/0470617888/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1331150309&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470617888)

SharePoint 2010 Workflows in Action
[http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2010-Workflows-Action-Wicklund/dp/1935182714/ref=sr_1_94?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1331150445&sr=1-94](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935182714)

Comment: ah. Sorry didn't read your whole post

Answer (score 0):

I read this book and it really helped me learn to actually build the workflows-  it was very focused on business people - he highlights no coding required and he wasn't kidding.  Very logically written.

[Sharepoint Workflows for Today's Knowledge Worker - from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01A755VYM)